# Rotate picture in user form

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

I'm trying to rotate an image inside an user form, here is the cose I'm using:

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias"GetTempPathA_(ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Dim NewPath As String

Function TempPath() As String
TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function

Sub RotatePic(deg As Long)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim p As Object
Dim chrt As Chart

'~~> Adding a temp sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

'~~> Insert the picture in the newly created worksheet
Set p = ws.Pictures.Insert(**PROBLEM**)

'~~> Rotate the pic
p.ShapeRange.IncrementRotation deg

'~~> Add a chart. This is required so that we can paste the picture in it
'~~> and export it as jpg
Set chrt = Charts.Add()

With ws
    '~~> Move the chart to the newly created sheet
    chrt.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ws.Name

    '~~> Resize the chart to match shapes picture. Notice that we are
    '~~> setting chart's width as the pictures `height` becuse even when
    '~~> the image is rotated, the Height and Width do not swap.
    With .Shapes(2)
        .Width = p.Height
        .Height = p.Width
    End With

    .Shapes(p.Name).Copy

    With ActiveChart
        .ChartArea.Select
        .Paste
    End With

    '~~> Temp path where we will save the pic
    NewPath = TempPath & "NewFile.Jpg"

    '~~> Export the image
    .ChartObjects(1).Chart.Export filename:=NewPath, FilterName:="jpg"
End With

'~~> Delete the temp sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

the problem (you can see PROBLEM in the code) is that I don't know how to get the path of the picture that is in image box (I upload the picture through a image dialog)
How can I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May simply try like this
[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\users\user\desktop\Range.jpg")
End Sub

Sub test()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, fname As String
Dim Shp As ShapeRange, p As Object
Dim Chrt As Chart
fname = "C:\users\user\desktop\TempXXX.jpg"
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
SavePicture Me.Image1.Picture, fname
DoEvents
Set p = Ws.Pictures.Insert(fname)
p.ShapeRange.Rotation = 90

    Ws.Shapes(p.Name).Copy
    Set Chrt = Ws.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, Ws.Shapes(p.Name).Height, Ws.Shapes(p.Name).Width).Chart
    Chrt.Paste

Chrt.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="jpg"
DoEvents
Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)
'clean temp objects
 Kill fname
 p.Delete
 Chrt.Parent.Delete
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
test
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The ".chart" method described above is a hack. It cost me 12 hours of debugging due to the code running faster than the system as it rotates large images (which is pretty much the standard for most phones and cameras these days). Issues such as the resulting image being a blank image, to the unchanged image being loaded back into the UserForm (because the code has run on to insert the image from the specified directory before the system has replaced it with the rotated image. No amount of Wait, Sleep, DoEvents, solved this. It works when stepping through fine but not in real-time for me, I'm afraid.
The solution is to implement the Windows Image Acquisition API. Daniel Pineault has developed a tidy VBA function [here](https://www.devhut.net/2017/05/14/vba-wia-rotate-an-image/comment-page-1/?unapproved=6271&moderation-hash=7315799760c05f906c273de8c01e9607#comment-6271). This should be the go-to solution.